# How to Shift Between Forms

Tags: c#-4.0

I am new to the programming and having a problem to keep values in their respective controls. I have created form1 and form2, form2 load a grid with values on double click the values are passed to form1 control textbox1 and form2 is hiding. Then I go to the next control and pull the values from form2 again but the form1 values disappear from the previous control.

Comment: It would be great if you could share what you have attempted so far ?

Comment: I am trying to find the solution on it how to handle this. Because when the values are fetched the form destroy the previous values.